# How to calculate the volume under a 3d plot in Python?

Tags: python, plot, data-analysis

We have been given a task to calculate an excavation volume using python given the 3D coordinates under a seabed. Is there a way, after plotting this, to calculate the volume under the 3D curve?

I have theoretically found ways that i can plot this using plotly or matplotlib however no features to calculate volume.

[example of data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fX0Vs.png) I would be plotting ( x, y, depth below LTC)

Comment: Is this a school assignment?  If so, what methods have you been taught that you are expected to use for this task?

Comment: We have been taught basic python e.g. matplotlib and other features which we are expected to use to solve the problem

Comment: Oh okay. Did they say anything about [numerical integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration)? There are various methods including in more than one dimension. Usually plotting libraries focus only on plotting, not on doing other calculations such as integration. Are your 3D co-ordinates on a regular grid? Please provide your data so we can see it.

Comment: Did you look at the answers to this question: [Volume under "plane" defined by data points - python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8792551/1609514).

Comment: I have added an example of the data set we were given. It contains approx 1000 data points. This is on a regular grid of, x intervals =18m (200-2000), y intervals = 10m (140-240). Then a given depth at each point.

Comment: An image of the data is no use. Please read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about how to ask good questions, in particular the part about not adding data as an image. It is impossible to tell what format your data is in (Excel, csv, pandas, Numpy array?). Share your code which loads the data into your program and ideally make an attempt to calculate the volume (see links I provided above for ideas).